# About encoding rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, encode

i have 2 application.. 
first in rails 1 or 2 i think, but another apps in rails 3 
apps 1 and 2 is interconected with same database..
in the view on app 1 there is special character "**≤**" and it's look normally in view, but in the field of database it turn to "**â‰¤**"
and when i take that field from database to another app (app in Rails 3), on view it just look same with database "**â‰¤**"..

How to encode "â‰¤" from database to "≤" on view in rails 3?

Comment: You have a UTF-8 encoding issue where one or more of your paths in the system are not encoding correctly. Check the encoding in your table and in your database configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a value that's expressed as UTF-8, then erroneously converted to and displayed as Windows-1252.

You'll need to track down where that encoding has slipped. It could be that your HTML document does not have its encoding set correctly, or the database connection, or any of the other things that can have a character set assigned.

Comment: thanks for explain..
i think my problem is on database connection ..
so what i do is make function to change the character .. xD

Comment: It usually involves `force_encode` to convert between the broken encoding and the correct one.